# Interpretation of results of "Energy Usage" instrument tool

Tags: ios, battery

I am running "energy usage" instrument over ios application using a device, I wanted to use it to check how much battery is getting drained because of the app I am testing. It shows "Energy usage level" which is giving me numbers like 13/20 , 12/20 , etc over different points of time.

How to interpret the results(I know, it gives relative energy usage on a scale of 0-20) in terms of :
1) How much battery is getting drained because of the app and particular operation.
2) Which operation / function is causing this drain.
3) What number is considered as safe and what number should be considered as high / too high.
4) Any other conclusion that we can make ?

I would appreciate if some one can answer above questions or give me link for reference. I have searched around and could not find answers to above questions, I just found how to find out those relative energy usage numbers only.

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents:

1) You can create a UIAutomation script to repeatedly run some actions, and collect 'energy usage' upon each action. So that you can say "if make a call of 5 minutes, it takes xxx battery", "if keep navigating for 5 minutes, it takes xxxx battery".....

2) As I mentioned above; You can collect data against each action

3) I would say, try to find similar apps, and bench mark, compare with theirs.

4) Try to use different devices, iOS, and you can probably tell customers that what device/iOS is minimal required or recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Energy Diagnostics reports power consumption number (we call them "electricities" at my office) are fairly unreliable.  [Powergremlin](http://blog.palominolabs.com/2012/11/14/introducing-powergremlin/) gives you some insight into the actual numbers that make up said "electicity" units.  That won't answer parts 2-4 of our question, but it does provide more detail and accuracy than Energy Diagnostics.

Answer (score -1):

The scale of Batter Consumption of IOS App is given by max 20 points.

if your app is running at 1/20,it means your app takes 20 hours to complete the batter

if it is running at 20/20 it takes 1 hour to complete the full batter.